# How to call a controller of custom module when a node is published?

Tags: 8, nodes

I am planning to make a module whose controller is called or method in that controller executes when a node is published. The module should be able to get the title and other properties of article that is set to published. Here is controller:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class myController extends ControllerBase
{
    //Function that should be executed when a specific node is published
    public function publish()
    {
     //here I should get title and other properties of the published node
    }
}
```

I am new to drupal, I have looked into web and found that the solution is related to hooks but I don't know how to use them. Any help regarding the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What would `publish()` exactly do, after getting those node properties?

Comment: @kiamlaluno it will use them to call an api

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am now working with hooks using the `hook_node_presave()` I am not able to get body of node (the content part of article and tags) is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of controllers is just providing output for a route, not implementing hooks. If you need to write code that is invoked when a node is published, you need to implement one of the following hooks:

- [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.6.x), invoked right before the entity is saved
- [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.6.x) (invoked after an entity is updated and saved in the database) and [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.6.x) (invoked after an entity is created and saved in the database)

`hook_node_presave()`, `hook_node_update()`, and `hook_node_insert()` get a `Node` object as parameter, so obtaining the body value is pretty easy.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function mymodule_node_presave(Node $node) {
  $body = $node->get('body')->value;
  $summary = $node->get('body')->summary;
}
```

Getting the taxonomy term from a reference field of a node can be achieved with code similar to the following one.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function mymodule_node_presave(Node $node) {
  $term = Term::load($node->get('field_tags')->target_id);
}
```

To that, you need to add the code to verify the node has been published.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function mymodule_node_presave(Node $node) {
  if ($node->status()) {
    // The node has been published.
    $body = $node->get('body')->value;
    $summary = $node->get('body')->summary;
    $term = Term::load($node->get('field_tags')->target_id);
    $term_name = $term->getName();
  }
}
```

If the taxonomy reference field is not *field_tags*, replace *field_tags* with the right machine name of the field.

Comment: Thank you for you response.  `$body = $node->get('body')->value;` gets title of node and `$summary = $node->get('body')->summary;` gets content of node?

Comment: No, both get the node body; the first gets the full body, while the second gets the trimmed body. For the node title, there is [`$node->getTitle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AgetTitle/8.6.x).

Comment: `$term_name = $term->getName();` provides only first tag. What if there are multiple tags to the article. @kiamlaluno

Comment: `$term_name = $term->getName();` provides only first tag. What if there are multiple tags to the article. @kiamlaluno

Comment: @HarisKhan That is a different, new question. I think it was already asked, but if there isn't a question like that, ask it.